# Анализ мата (ненормативной лексики) в переменной python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, pymorphy2

Есть переменная `str(event)` (да Vk-api) как её просканировать на мат по мимо `or 'text' in str(event)`

Вот что-то в таком виде у меня сейчас есть, но мне нужно чтобы переменная сканировалась на почти весь мат который есть в русском языке
Я так и не понял как это сделать через PyMormphy2

```
                if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if 'text' in str(event):
                    if event.from_chat:
```

Comment: Подстрахуй, оскорблять, колебаться...

Comment: Как наглядно проиллюстрировал andreymal, искать маты внутри слов бесполезно. Единственный вариант хоть отсеять мат - проверять каждое слово, является ли оно целиком матом. Для этого нужно составить базу матерных слов и искать каждое слово в ней: `flag = any(word in ban_list for word in message.split())`. Зачем тут использовать pymorphy2 я не понимаю. Возможно, для того, чтобы приводить маты в начальную форму перед поиском в базе - как это делается достаточно хорошо описано в документации: https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/guide.html

Comment: Спасибо за помощь