# Как сделать обнаружение запрещенных слов в чате? Telebot, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать фильтрацию по словам в чате. Я написал такой код, но столкнулся со следующими проблемами: Если запретить писать слово "Пример1", то нельзя будет писать и слово "Пример", то есть цифра 1 на конце вроде как учитывается, а вроде как и нет. Буду благодарен если кто-то сможет предложить более удачную идею для решения моей задачи.

```
message_words = message.text.split()
for word in message_words:
    if word.lower() not in DB.blacklisted_words_get(message.chat.id):
        pass
    else:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<a href="tg://user?id={user_id}">{user_name}</a>, '
        'Вы использовали запрещенное слово!', parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281263

Comment: Вот еще в дополнение :) https://habr.com/ru/post/114997/

Answer (score 0):

у вас задом наперед построена логика

попробуйте такой код:

```
restricted_words=["слово1","слово2"] и так далее полный набор
```

потом если надо удалить все сообщение то можно сделать так:

```
for restricted_word in restricted_words:
    if len(message)>len(message.replace(restricted_word,""):
       message="Сообщение удалено"
       break
```

если надо заменять отдельные слова то можно сделать так же:

```
for restricted_word in restricted_words:
    message=message.replace(restricted_word,"-_-")
```

ну и потом возвращаем message обратно на вывод.

Проблема очевидна - всякие реконструкции через латиницу или 1337 стайл оскорбления все еще будут проходить. А что бы не проходили надо написать небольшой лингво-движок, который и "потреблять" не забанит, "xy*" тоже распознает. Но это совсем другая история.

Answer (score -2):

Советую тебе создать массив запретных слов и уже каждое слово из СООБЩЕНИЯ сравнивать с каждым словом из МАССИВА. Ибо Пример содержится в строке Пример1, а Пример1 в Пример уже не содержится, понимаешь?:)

И сравнивать не с помощью `if <Пример1> in <Массив слов сообщения>`, а с помощью `if <Пример1> == <Пример>`, точно не прогадаешь. Хотя и так и так может сработать, главное именно массивы держать.

Comment: Если сравнивать через ==, то придётся вносить в список все словоформы.